# What causes outOfBounds error in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having the following issue raised by Crashlytics :

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 5 beyond bounds for empty array
-TopicListViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
```

While accessing the dataSource with `indexPath.row`.

We have some asynchronous data update updating the datasource, and that variable is nonatomic.

Would it be possible that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called while the dataSource is being updated? Hence causing to access an index that doesn't exist anymore?

Can it be because the variable is nonatomic?

Here's the relevant code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row > [self.tableData count] - 1 || ![self.tableData isValidArray]) {
        return nil; //Some protection to prevent this issue...
    }

    TopicCell * cell = (TopicCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary * data = nil;

    if (self.we_isSearching) {
        data = self.we_searchResult[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        data = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //Crashes here
    }
```

Comment: Update your question with your `numberOfRowsInSection` method and the rest of your `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: It clearly shows that your `numberOfRowsInSection` is greater than the size of array you are accessing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` so it's exceeding the index and throwing error.

Comment: update your code with 'numberOfRowsInSection' method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`index 5 beyond bounds for empty array`" simply states that either you didn't initialise your array or the range of the value you're accessing is out of the range of the array. You are trying to access index 5 in an empty/having less element array, or non initialised array that's why it is giving you "outOfBounds" in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Would it be possible that cellForRowAtIndexPath is called while the dataSource is being updated?

Yes, cellForRowAtIndexPath will always be called when you're going to see a new tableview cell for example when you're scrolling the tableview Or in case you've added some kind of notification added to your datasource or by reloading the tableview.

You can put a break point at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and check the stack trace maybe you get something that causes the tableview to reload.

Comment: Do you know a way to prevent this behavior from happening? I feel like a race condition is the cause of the crashes.

Comment: you have to first identify when and why you're tableview is reloading and at the same time try to identify your datasource is correct or not this may be happening by the unnecessary reloading of tableview at the wrong movement. to prevent that just add and check in your cellForRowAtIndexPath and check the index is in the range of your datasource or not!

Comment: Issue was caused by raced condition with the we_searchResult array when loading a lot of data with batches asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Try to count from self.tableData in return of `numberOfRowsInSection` methods. Like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      {

     return [self.tableData count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass array count in numberOfRowsInSection of tableView method.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return array.count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your condition

```
if (indexPath.row > [self.tableData count] - 1 || ![self.tableData isValidArray])
```

is wrong. If there is 5 elements, the last indexPath.row will be index 4 so condition with real values will be:

```
if (4 > 5 - 1) --> if 4 > 4
```

So the valid condition is:

```
if (indexPath.row >= [self.tableData count] - 1)
```

But with correct condition you will have crash on:

```
return nil
```

Because obvisously your data source is different than table data source. Your model data source should be always same as table data source.